# What's the layer limit where overlapping fields no longer get darker on the intel map or the radar?

Tags: ingress

What's the layer limit where overlapping fields no longer get darker on the intel map or the radar? I heard once that it's 8 layers but I can't be sure about it. I've haven't built more than 8 layers yet and didn't pay attention before to notice the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scanner gets completely featureless after 12 fields. The limit for the intel map is further.